# Are community users stored in salesforce as users or contacts?

Tags: community, partner-communities, user-management, user-record

I really apologize but I have these basic questions on how communities work:

1) Every user who is logging into communities are stored in Salesforce as User objects or Contact objects?

2) We have hundred reseller companies and each reseller company has 10 users who need access to communities..Does it mean we need to buy 100*10 salesforce user licences?

3) I guess I need to create one partner community irrespective of how many reseller companies we have?

4) The [Communities Pricing](http://www.salesforce.com/communities/pricing/) page shows that it is starting at 700$/month. Does any body know what is this "starting" keyword signifies?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are the answers that I can provide you with:

1. Every Community User will have both a User record and a Contact Record. All Community Users have profiles. Only Partner Users have Roles.
2. Will you need to purchase 10,000 licenses? Not necessarily. You'll need to contact your Account Representative to discuss your options once you determine your needs for access to objects and visibility of Portal Users. Some licenses are based on "Average Usage" and will allow for "Peak Usage" during busy times of the year. The HVC (High Volume Customer) license in particular operates like that, but is limited in terms of the objects your users have access to. However, it's much less expensive than other licenses.
3. Again, that will depend on your needs for Partner Access to your information. A partner community will operate separately from other communities you might create.
4. I'd expect the "starting" keyword to represent the minimum number of licenses included with that price. Additional licenses and "ala carte" features would of course be additional.

The only way to get your questions answered accurately is to speak to an account representative. Click on the link on the page you referenced and speak to someone in sales who can provide you with answers while advising you on available options and the associated limitations with each one. Honestly, the last time I heard, they don't bite and will be happy to assist you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1)Customer community User is contact as well as user .A community user is a contact but once provisioned access for community ,sfdc creates a User out of that contact with contactId as the Salesforce Contact

2)Explore Employee community license as for most of cases thats sufficient unless you need full access to knowledge and other features

3)Partner community will be needed if your partners will need to manage their selling process inside your SFDC instance via the portal

4)Pricing always you need to reach to your salesforce AE for confirmation